# Javascript condition operators not functioning how I thought they would

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make my button change state depending on a boolean. This looks like it would work and I thought it would but it just changes to white.

Any idea why? Please help.

```
function dropDown(){
    var isClicked = false;
    var button = document.getElementById("bigbutton");

    if(isClicked == false){
        button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        isClicked = true;
    }

    if(isClicked == true){
        button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        isClicked = false;
    }        
}
```

Comment: You should use `else if` for the second statement otherwise it will always be true (since the first statement will make isClicked true if it isn't already).

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use else or return. Right now, you are setting isClicked to false, getting the element, then running through the first if block. Then you set isClicked to true, and it will then run the second if block. What you probably want is:

```
if(isClicked){
    button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    isClicked = false;
} else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    isClicked = true;
}
```

However, this probably also won't work because isClicked is local to this function so will always be false. What you should do instead is check for a property of the button, perhaps the backgroundColor, and use that as the conditional instead:

```
var bgColor = button.style.backgroundColor
if(bgColor === "red"){
    button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
} else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate `if` statements. The second one always runs after the first one. So, when the first one is done, it has set `isClicked` to `true`, so then the second one runs and sees the `true` value and sets the color to white.

You need to combine the two statements into a "one or the other" operation with an `else` branch. Also, with booleans, you don't need to test explicitly for `true` or `false` in an `if` statement because `if` conditions are always evaluated for `true`.

```
function dropDown(){

  var isClicked = false;
  var button = document.getElementById("bigbutton");

  // This implicitly tests isClicked for true
  if(isClicked){
    button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    isClicked = true;
  } else { 
    // If the earlier condition failed, the else branch is automatically run
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    isClicked = false;
  }
}
```

Having said this, your function sets `isClicked` to `false` right away, so you are always going to fall into the `else` branch. You should not set an initial value for that and instead declare the variable at a higher scope, like this:

```
// We'll declare these at a higher scope so we don't keep establishing them
// every time the function runs:
var isClicked = null;
var button = document.getElementById("bigbutton");

function dropDown(){
  // This implicitly tests isClicked for true
  if(isClicked){
    button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    isClicked = true;
  } else { 
    // If the earlier condition failed, the else branch is automatically run
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    isClicked = false;
  }
}
```

Lastly, if I understand your scenario correctly, you may not actually need JavaScript at all for this:

```css
button { background-color:white;}
button:active { background-color:red;}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Now can you show that the `if` is useless since you set the var to false then immediately check what it is.

Comment: @takendarkk The entire scenario doesn't make sense, but this code stops the error that the OP is getting and explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code will run from the top down. So you start with isClicked false so the first `if` is satisfied, setting the background red. In the `if` you set the isclicked true, so the next if statement is then satisfied, turning the background color white.

The end result is your background color is white.

You likely want to set the isclicked on a 'click' event of your button.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet doesn't really make sense, you should get the click value as an event, if you set it to `false` in your code you don't gain anything.

```
$( "#yourButtonID" ).click(function() {
     button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
```

And outside the function (on page load, in my example) set the color to red:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```